# VirtualBox on Debian

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I have two kernels installed, 3.5.0 and 3.6.0. For several reasons I
have to run kernel 3.5.0. VirtualBox works perfectly on 3.6.0, but
not on 3.5.0.

After I booted kernel 3.5.0 I triggered a module rebuild of the with `apt-get --reinstall install
virtualbox-dkms`. This recompiled the VirtualBox module successfully. However,
it fails to load.

```
# modprobe vboxdrv
ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Exec format error

/var/log/messages:

warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
vboxdrv: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

The module seems to be installed correctly:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/
vboxdrv.ko  vboxnetadp.ko  vboxnetflt.ko  vboxpci.ko
```

System information: Debian unstable, package `virtualbox-dkms` is installed

```
$ uname -r
3.5.0

$ apt-cache show virtualbox | grep Version
Version: 4.1.18-dfsg-1.1

$ apt-cache show dkms | grep Version
Version: 2.2.0.3-1.2
```

Here is the output of the module build:

```
-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 4.1.18
Kernel:  3.5.0 (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 4.1.18
Kernel:  3.6.0 (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 4.1.18
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking replacement virtualbox-dkms ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.1.18-dfsg-1.1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.18 DKMS files...
Building for 3.5.0 and 3.6.0
Building initial module for 3.5.0
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Building initial module for 3.6.0
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.6.0/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
[ ok ] Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules.
[FAIL] Starting VirtualBox kernel modules[....] modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why ... failed!
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

How can I get VirtualBox to work on 3.5.0?

Comment: `apt-cache show` will show the highest priority version, which may or may not be the one installed. Use `apt-cache policy <package>`

Comment: You probably need to get the kernel headers(or sources) of 3.5.0 version to recompile it

Comment: @jordanm The versions I show are ones actually installed.

Comment: @Serge The package `linux-headers-3.5.0` is installed. Otherwise the modules would not have been built and placed in `/var/lib/modules/3.5.0` I assume.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then I have no advice

Comment: Just re-build the modules, it means it's incompatible with current kernel

Comment: @warl0ck That's what I don't understand. I already rebuilt the modules. Can I somehow confirm that the modules placed in `/lib/modules/3.5.0` are actually compiled for 3.5.0?

Comment: What's the output of `find /lib/modules -name 'vbox*.ko'`?

Comment: @Marco I mean there might be another "vboxdrv.ko" and kernel is loading the wrong one

Comment: @warl0ck Good idea, but it's not. Only the files I listed in the `ls` output (twice).

Comment: This thread clearly tell you about the error message http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720177/module-layout-version-incompatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link from warlock I figured that there was
some version mismatch. I assume it was
caused by the fact that I didn't create a `kernel-source` package.
Instead I was using the git repository which was used to compile several other versions as well.

First I deleted the packages `linux-image` and `linux-headers`
(the currently running kernel).

The next step was a completely clean checkout (without build remains in the
directory). Then I built the kernel and created the packges
`linux-image`, `linux-headers` and the `linux-source` package and
installed them. After this the VirtualBox module was built
and its loading succeeded.

I don't know which versions didn't match before, but following these
steps guarantees that there should be no version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `virtualbox-dkms` package installed?
I usually have to reinstall this after each kernel upgrade, which I think indicates that the dkms part of it is broken, but re-installing it works for me. I've never tried re-installing it on anything but a new kernel, but I assume it should build against whichever kernel is currently running.

Comment: Yes, `virtualbox-dkms` is installed. I triggered a rebuild with reinstalling the `dkms` package as mentioned in my question and the modules are successfully built.